# Why is downloadHandler not being set using loop and action button surrogate?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, download, shinyjs

I want a number of action buttons created using `renderUI` to trigger downloads. The action button-to-download button transfer is working, but the `downloadHandler` is not, as button clicks prompt to download "download.html". How can I fix this?

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  sliderInput("slider", label = "num buttons", min = 1, max = 10, step = 1, value = 2),
  uiOutput("buttons")
)

observers = list()

server = function(input, output)
{
  observe({
    output$buttons = renderUI({
      lapply(1:input$slider, function(i)
      {
        
        buttonId = paste0("button_", i)
        downloadButtonId = paste0("download_button_", i)
        
        observers[[buttonId]] <<- observe({
          runjs(paste0("$('#", downloadButtonId, "')[0].click();"))
        }) %>% bindEvent(input[[buttonId]])
        
        div(conditionalPanel("false", downloadButton(downloadButtonId)),
            HTML(paste0('<button id="', buttonId, '" type="button" class="action-button">', buttonId, '</button>'))
        )
      })
    })
    
      lapply(1:input$slider, function(i)
      {
        downloadButtonId = paste0("download_button_", i)
        output[[downloadButtonId]] = downloadHandler(
          filename = function()
          {
            return("cars.csv")
          },
          content = function(file)
          {
            write.csv(mtcars, file)
          }
        )
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```